# favicon - strategy that is simple yet reasonably complete

Tags: ios, microsoft-metro, favicon

I'm looking for a favicon strategy which (if possible):

- looks pretty good in modern browsers, iOS bookmarks, metro tiles, etc.
- is reasonably easy to implement
- minimizes html markup

I don't care about:

- bandwidth
- the "long tail" of legacy browser versions, low-volume browsers and devices, etc.
- perfect image quality (but I don't want it to look obviously bad or broken in modern browser/device contexts)

I'm thinking of just putting a single favicon.ico in my site root, containing many resolutions (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23375619/3657991).

Would any of the situations I care about, as outlined above, simply ignore a favicon.ico in the site root?

If my suggested strategy is insufficient, can you suggest another strategy that is a good compromise between coverage and simplicity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the Real Favicon Generator: http://realfavicongenerator.net/

I've studied and read a lot on this subject and it's much more complicated than you would think! The Real Favicon Generator does a great job at covering as many browsers and devices as possible. It also has a tester, so you can test how your mentioned strategy would do.

It will generate all the images/icons and code for you. Just follow the directions.

Comment: thanks. i'm aware of that site, and i may very well end up using it, but i'm hoping for simpler solution, if possible.

Comment: i have gone ahead with this solution. it is very easy to implement, and it looks good everywhere i've tried so far, including various desktop browsers, iOS bookmarks, and metro tiles. the cost is 17 lines of markup and 22 files... sigh... i wonder how often i'll have to repeat the process, to keep current.

Comment: If you are finished with this question you should mark it answered.

Comment: i was waiting to see if any more perspectives would come to light, but no activity in the last 8 days, so i'm marking it answered now. thanks again for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `ios` guess you care how the icon would look like if one adds your page to Home-screen. So consider adding more icons and probably splash screens:

```
<!-- Icons and iOS splash -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="client_files/images/app_icon_57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="client_files/images/app_icon_72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="client_files/images/app_icon_114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="client_files/images/app_icon_144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="client_files/images/splash_320x460.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="640x920" href="client_files/images/splash_640x920.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="client_files/images/splash_768x1004.png" media="(min-device-width: 720px) and (orientation: portrait)" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1024x748" href="client_files/images/splash_1024x748.png" media="(min-device-width: 720px) and (orientation: landscape)" />
```

Some sizes have been changed, so feel free to edit this answer.

Some articles:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html
  (Safari, iOS)
- https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen
  (Chrome, Android)

Comment: thanks. if i don't include markup like the above, will iOS devices use the same-sized images from my site root favicon.ico, or will they simply ignore the favicon.ico and use a generic default image?

Comment: Im not sure, I know Android grabs kind of screenshot, think iPhone does same.